# When to use compile-only dependencies in Elixir

Tags: elixir, exrm

When would it be appropriate to specify a dependency only in `deps` in my `mix.exs` and not as a runtime dependency in `applications`?

I thought that `applications` are actual applications that need to be started before my own application can be started, but I run into a problem where `exrm` wasn't putting the `Jazz` library (which I think only contains pure functions) into the release until I included `:jazz` in `applications`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An OTP application is more like a component - a bunch of modules and functions that may (but need not) run some processes. If an OTP app doesn't start its own supervision tree, it is called a library application. Either way, if you use some of libs functions at runtime, you need to specify it as a runtime dep.

In contrast, compile-time dependency only ensures that the 3rd party code is fetched and available locally (on your dev/build machine). This is useful if the 3rd party code does its magic outside of runtime. An example could be my own [ExActor](https://github.com/sasa1977/exactor) or pure Erlang [meck](https://github.com/eproxus/meck) mocking library. In the first case ExActor does its magic during compilation, while in the second case you need the mocking library only during tests.